# Simple angular.js example sometimes doesn't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:**

I started using angular.js for my project and during development I noticed that controller sometimes doesn't load, so I tried removing parts of the project until the smallest possible example but the problem still remains.

**Code:**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input ng-model="testText" type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
    </div>
    <script src="/static/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.js*

```
console.log("INIT");
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.testText = '172.17.2.1';
    console.log("SCOPE");
}]);
```

**Note:**

"INIT" part always gets displayed in console. Altough "SCOPE" part sometimes (or most of the time) doesn't so the input field doesn't get filled.

**Versions:**

> Chrome: 36.0.1985.125
>
> Angular.js: 1.3.14

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/g33ct2ah/ Are there no errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors in javascript console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem was "AngularJS Batarang" extension for Chrome. It was somehow messing up with the angular. I never actually used it, installed it sometime ago when researching angular.js and forgot it enabled.

I disabled it and everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Was just driving myself batty trying to figure out why my views would intermittently not load.  Disabled Batarang and everything works as it should have.